# What pattern to use in a html input field to validate french numbers format?

Tags: html, design-patterns, input, numbers, french

I am looking for the right pattern allowing to validate french numbers (positive integers) in an HTML input.

i.e. thousand separator is a "space".

Ex. of correct values:

1

12 345

1 234 567

Ex. of incorrect:

12x

2x1

1237

I have tried the pattern bellow, but it does not work

`<input pattern="([0-9]*[ ]*)*"/>`

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

try this -

```
<input pattern="[0-9 ]+"/>
```

Note: there is a space before **]**

in javascript you can get actual number by replacing all " "(spaces) with "" and converting the string to integer

Comment: do accept my answer if found useful (the tick on the left side of my answer)

Comment: Please do not add a comment on your question or on an answer to say "Thank you", instead accept the most helpful answer => https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers